# Is it save to store server response in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I would like to store my server response as a string in Shared Preferences so that I can use this response later without fetching from server. But when I saved the data in Shared Preferences and later I use I miss the whole response. I have no security issue and any other cause like uninstall app etc. My question is whether the response will be lost in Shared Preferences so that the response contain multiple JSONObject and JSONArray.

```
private void productListApi(String url){
    final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    pDialog.setMessage(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.loading_message));
    pDialog.show();
    System.out.println("product list urlllllllllllllllllllll:" + url);

    RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext.getApplicationContext());

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println("response of product list data is:"
                            + response);
                    apiResponse = response ;
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (json.has("code")) {

                            if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("200")) {

                                //set response to shared preference
                                SharedPreference.setStringValue(mContext, SharedPreference.PRODUCT_LIST_RESPONSE, response);

                                parseData(SharedPreference.getStringValue(mContext,SharedPreference.PRODUCT_LIST_RESPONSE));


                            }else {
                                UserDialog
                                        .showUserAlert(mContext,
                                                mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.product_list_failed));
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            pDialog.dismiss();
            UserDialog.showUserAlert(mContext,
                    mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.no_response));
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            // the POST parameters:

            params.put("user_id", SharedPreference.getStringValue(getActivity(), SharedPreference.USER_ID));
            params.put("temp_user_id", SharedPreference.getStringValue(getActivity(), SharedPreference.TEMP_USER_ID));
            params.put("version", Utilities.getVersionCode(mContext));
            params.put("device_token", SharedPreference.getStringValue(getActivity(), SharedPreference.DEVICE_TOKEN));
            return params;
        }
    };

    int socketTimeout = Constant.socketTimeout
            ;//30 seconds - change to what you want
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    //RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    postRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    mRequestQueue.add(postRequest);

}
public class SharedPreference {

SharedPreferences preferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

private static final String PREFS_NAME = "nevada_food";

public static final String PRODUCT_LIST_RESPONSE = "product_list" ;

public SharedPreference() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static String getStringValue(final Context context, String key) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getString(key, "");
}

public static void setStringValue(final Context context, String key,
                                  String value) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
            PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

this is my server response. I saved it in Shared Preferences and parse data in UI from Shared Preferences. This method
   parseData(SharedPreference.getStringValue(mContext,SharedPreference.PRODUCT_LIST_RESPONSE));
works properly first time when directly from server but when we use this method in another it does not work.

Comment: No you may be clearing preferences somewhere.Is it saving properly

Comment: can you show some code snippet that how you are saving the response and how retriving

Comment: You can also use the sqlite for it..

Comment: don't use `SharedPreferences` to store server response instead cache it in a sqlite db as TEXT!

Comment: You can also use caching library for store server response or you can store json as a string in shared preferences.

Comment: instend of sharedPreference try volly libaray its store your response in cache

Comment: @JanardhanR It is saved properly because first time I show response from shared preferences

Comment: @Zahidul you can try my answer and make sure you understand `SharedPreference` properly

Answer (score 1):

**Data stored in `SharedPreference` does not loss until unless:**

1. You clear it by manually or programmatically.
2. Any cache clearing application won't clear application cache.
3. You uninstall your application.

**Depending on scenario you can opt from following approach to save/cache your json data/response:**

1. `SharedPreference` more convenient to use.
2. Writing it text file as private or public in external/internal storage. Data stored in external store won't loss even if you uninstall application.
3. If json is big and there is trade off associated with calling server every time you can go creating `Sqlite` database or can choose ORM tools like ORMLite, GreeDao etc.
4. Caching library can be used to cache server response.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is whether the response will be lost in Shared Preferences

Shared preferences won't be removed/lost, unless:

1. you remove them
2. user clears app data

So, you are safe to store there necessary data.

Comment: Or: 0. You failed to save them properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong way to save into SharedPreference.

Your Code:

```
 //set response to shared preference
  SharedPreference.setStringValue(mContext, SharedPreference.PRODUCT_LIST_RESPONSE, response);
  parseData(SharedPreference.getStringValue(mContext,SharedPreference.PRODUCT_LIST_RESPONSE));
```

I don't have any clue what you written here. Try my solution below.

You should have to follow the simple [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) format followed by its Editor.

Just save your data like below:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", 0).edit();
editor.putString("PRODUCT_LIST_RESPONSE", response);
editor.commit();
```

And get it by the **KEY** (*PRODUCT_LIST_RESPONSE* here)

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFS_NAME", 0); 
String response = prefs.getString("PRODUCT_LIST_RESPONSE", any_default_Value);
```

Comment: I have updated my question to add my custom class SharedPreference where I declare SharedPreferences property.